# How to upload/push files in folderB to remote repo without adding and commiting certain files form folderA

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

I have two working folders, say fA and fB. I make changes in both fA and fB. I want to commit and push fB first with a particular commit message (e.g. "changes made to fB)" that is not relevant to fA.

How can I do that?

When I add all modified/new/deleted files within fB, (git add fb/*), the *git commit*, do the *git pull --rebase origin main* from the remote repo, I get the error:

> error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes. error:

> please commit or stash them.

I understand why I am getting this error because files changed in fA are not added and committed, but I don't want to do that commit now. Is it possible to do what I want?

**Edit:** One thing I am thinking of is put the files/folder in .gitignore that I don't want to commit now, and later remove them from the .gitignore, but this is pretty manual and time-consuming task if I have to repeat again and again.